How to make the specific filling in the plot
Consider the following curves:
Factor1[mX_, g2_] = 10^18 Sqrt[1 - mX^2/5^2]*g2;
ldecay[mX_, g2_] = (5.*10^-13)/(100*mX^4*g2);
lmin = 10;
lmax = 100;
Factor2[mX_, g2_] = Exp[-10/ldecay[mX, g2]] - Exp[-100/ldecay[mX, g2]];
ToyModification[mX_] = 
  If[mX < 0.2 || mX > 2, 1, 1/Exp[2 (mX - 0.2) (2 - mX)]];
func1[mX_, g2_] = 
  If[mX < 5, Evaluate[Factor1[mX, g2]*Factor2[mX, g2]], 0];
func2[mX_, g2_] = 
  If[mX < 5, 
   Evaluate[Factor1[mX, g2]*ToyModification[mX]*Factor2[mX, g2]], 0];
ToyRegions = 
  RegionPlot[#[mX, 10^g2] >= 3, {mX, 0.1, 7}, {g2, -20, -7}, 
     PlotPoints -> 30] & /@ {func1, func2};
ToySensitivityCurves = {#[[1]], 10^#[[2]]} & /@ 
     Partition[
      Flatten[Cases[Normal@ToyRegions[[#]], Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]],
       2] & /@ {1, 2};

I would like to make a specific filling between the 1st and the 2nd curves in the domain where they are different. This is my attempt:
ListLogLogPlot[Evaluate[ToySensitivityCurves], Joined -> {True, True},
  Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]},1 -> {{2}, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.1, 7}, {10^-20, 10^-7}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thickness[0.003],
     Darker@Gray}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], 
 Joined -> {True, True, True, True, True}, AspectRatio -> 0.66, 
 ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["func > 3", 22, Black]]

However, the filling only occurs at the upper boundary and not at the lower boundary:

Could you please tell me how to make the proper filling?

Method-1

RegionSymmetricDifference the Polygon regions.

ListLogLogPlot[Evaluate[ToySensitivityCurves], Joined -> {True, True},
  Frame -> True, 
 Epilog -> {Red, 
   RegionSymmetricDifference@@ (Polygon /@ ({Log@#, Log@#} & /@ 
        ToySensitivityCurves))}]


Method-2

Reverse the points.

plot1 = ListLogLogPlot[ToySensitivityCurves, Joined -> {True, True}, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]}}, 
   Frame -> True];
plot2 = ListLogLogPlot[Reverse[ToySensitivityCurves, 2], 
   Joined -> {True, True}, 
   Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]}}];
Show[plot1, plot2]



The following method also works:
ListLogLogPlot[Evaluate[ToySensitivityCurves], Joined -> {True, True},
  Filling -> {1 -> {True, Directive[Gray, Opacity[0.2]]},2 -> {True, Directive[White]}}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 25], 
 PlotRange -> {{0.1, 7}, {10^-20, 10^-7}}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003], Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], 
    Blue}, {Thickness[0.003], Darker@Darker@Green}, {Thickness[0.003],
     Darker@Gray}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 22], 
 Joined -> {True, True, True, True, True}, AspectRatio -> 0.66, 
 ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["func > 3", 22, Black]]

There, I just fill the domain inside the curve covering larger space with gray, and the domain inside the curve covering smaller space with white.
It works in some peculiar cases when the option Filling -> {1 -> {{2} is not an option (some very sharp regions, etc.).
